# How to get last month row sum in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I need to get last month transactions amount sum , I wrote query but getting error `Error: Call to undefined function App\Controller\YEAR()`

```
// sum of total received amount 
  $conditions['transaction_type']=1;
  $conditions['AND']['YEAR(Transactions.created) >='] = YEAR('CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH');
  $conditions['AND']['MONTH(Transactions.created) <='] = MONTH('CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH');
  $query = $this->Transactions->find('all',['conditions'=>$conditions]); 
  $collection = new Collection($query);
  $sumOfReceivedAmount =  $collection->sumOf('amount');
  $this->set('sumOfReceivedAmount',$sumOfReceivedAmount);
```

I have also tried using query builder

```
$query = $this->Transactions->find()
               ->where(function ($exp, $q) {
                     $year = $q->func()->year([
                          'created' => 'identifier'
                     ]);
                     $month = $q->func()->month([
                          'created' => 'identifier'
                     ]);
                     return $exp
                     ->eq($year, $q->func()->year(['CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH']))
                     ->eq($month, $q->func()->month(['CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH']));
 });
```

For this code I am getting query like

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  transactions Transactions 
WHERE 
  (
    year(created) = (
      year(
        'CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH'
      )
    ) 
    AND month(created) = (
      month(
        'CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH'
      )
    )
  )
```

Problem is this single quote `'CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH'`

How can I remove this single quote ?

Comment: you're missing quote before YEAR.. eg: `"YEAR('CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH')";` and also `"MONTH('CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH')";`

Comment: After used your comment I got empty result without array. Here I got the query with single quote. 
YEAR(Transactions.created) >= 'YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)'  
That should be 
YEAR(Transactions.created) >= YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to your other `year()` usage where you decalare the passed value to be an `identifier`, you'd have to declare your other values as `literal` values (or pass expression objects) so that they are inserted into the query as is, instead of being bound.

```
['CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH' => 'literal']
```

CakePHP also ships with methods to express similar functionality, specifically the `FunctionsBuilder::dateAdd()` method. Also when expressing `CURRENT_DATE` as a function the query builder will be able to convert the SQL for other DBMS like SqlServer, which has no `CURRENT_DATE`:

```
$q->func()->year(
    [$q->func()->dateAdd($q->func()->CURRENT_DATE(), -1, 'MONTH')]
)
```

`NOW()` should work too:

```
$q->func()->dateAdd($q->func()->now(), -1, 'MONTH')
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Using SQL Functions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-sql-functions)**